# Change file name from Cell in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm new to all this but I did copy a script from Ali which will do exactly what I need and worked for a time however now  I get a Exception: Service Error: Drive Message. Nothing changed but this error keeps happening. The script I'm using is below```

```
function CHNAME()
```

{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("c5").getValue(); //assuming you want to add the string in C5 to your title

```
  var name = sheet.rename(range)

 }
```

```
I expected the file name to change but get the error described above
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename Sheet From Cell Value

```
function setColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.setName(sh.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue());
}
```

Using parameter

```
function setColumn(a1rg="A1") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.setName(sh.getRange(a1rg).getDisplayValue());
}
```